# split json data into 3 lists - jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, list

I have json data 
I've taken the first set of data and written it to one ul. 
I want to split the remaining data into 2 equal chunks and write to two other uls.

How do I split the remaining json after the initial index == 0?

my js code:

```
$("#storeList").append('<ul class="storeListLeft"></ul>');
    $("#storeList").append('<ul class="storeListRight"></ul>');

    //run store json data and append to storeList div
                                var object;
                                $.getJSON('xml/storeList.json', function(json) {
                                    object = json;
                                    $.each(object.storeList.state, function(index, value) {
                                    var list;
                                        if(index == 0) {
                                          list = $('.storeListLeft');
                                        } else {
                                          list = $('.storeListRight');
                                        }

                                            listItem = $('<li/>'),
                                            html = listItem.append($('<h3/>').text(this.stateName));

                                        $.each(this.store, function() {
                                            listItem.append($('<a />').attr('href', this.storeURL).attr('class', 'storeInactive').attr('id', this.storeID).text(this.storeName));
                                        });

                                        list.append(html)

                                    });
                                }); //end json render
```

CUrrent output:

```
<ul class="storeListLeft">
   <li>
       <h3>state Name</h3>
       <a>store Name</a>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul class="storeListRight">
   <li>
       <h3>state Name</h3>
       <a>store Name</a>
       <a>store Name</a>
       <a>store Name</a>
   </li>
    <li>
       <h3>state Name</h3>
       <a>store Name</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

my desired output is to still assign the first item to the storeListLeft, and then split the remaining data and assign the chunks to 2 separate uls

so something like this:

```
<ul class="storeList_1"> //which is index == 0
   <li>
       <h3>state Name</h3>
       <a>store Name</a>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul class="storeList_2"> //2 & 3 are the split of the remainder after index == 0 
   <li>
       <h3>state Name</h3>
       <a>store Name</a>
       <a>store Name</a>
       <a>store Name</a>
   </li>
    <li>
       <h3>state Name</h3>
       <a>store Name</a>
   </li>
</ul>
<ul class="storeList_3">
   <li>
       <h3>state Name</h3>
       <a>store Name</a>
       <a>store Name</a>
       <a>store Name</a>
   </li>
    <li>
       <h3>state Name</h3>
       <a>store Name</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What does your list look like ?

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Comment: If you really just want to split the list into two columns can you not just split the array into the two lists and then call your function to do the work on each list rather than make the split decisions within the function?

Comment: I'm not sure how to split the array, in conjunction with that I am detaching the first item and appending it to "storeListLeft" and the rest I am appending to "storeListRight". Would I set a third ul, and then split the array (unsure how) and append the 2 parts to the separate lists?

Comment: @Jason Could you provide some sample output?

Comment: @Jason great, could you show the desired output of at least 2 states?

Comment: @Jason Should each storeListLeft contain each state plus the first store in that state? Then all OTHER stores in that state are added to the storeListRight?

Comment: @Craig - see edit - I currently already have the json split into 2 lists - see my if else statement, which is taking the index == 0 and appending it left and the rest is appended to right. But I want to split the json into 3 lists - index 0 in one list, and the rest divided equally.

Comment: @Jason pretty sure I've got you now...posted a new answer.

Comment: @Craig - see further comment below, I'm still screwing something up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the first loop break the states into the objects you want:

```
//get the first state element in the array
var firstStateArray = object.storeList.state.slice(0, 1);

//get the half way point of the states
var mid = Math.round((object.storeList.state.length - 1) / 2);

//assign the first half of the array, starting at the second item (1) to the middle (mid)
var secondStateArray = object.storeList.state.slice(1, mid);

//assign the second half of the array but starting after the first half
var thirdStateArray = object.storeList.state.slice(mid + 1);
```

Here is a function to generate the markup:

```
function GenerateMarkup(states, className) {
    var html = "<ul class='" + className + "'>";

    $.each(states, function () {

        html += "<li>";

        html += "<h3>" + this.stateName + "</h3>";

        $.each(this.store, function (index, value) {
            html += "<a href='" + this.storeURL + "' class='storeInactive' id='" + this.storeID + "'>" + this.storeName + "</a>";
        });

        html += "</li>";

    });

    html += "</ul>";

    $("#storeList").append(html);
}
```

And calling the function:

```
//create first list...only one state
GenerateMarkup(firstStateArray, "storeList_1");

//create second list
GenerateMarkup(secondStateArray, "storeList_2");

//create third list
GenerateMarkup(thirdStateArray, "storeList_3");
```

Comment: I'm botching it somewhere. How would I run the loop and append to the right ul?

Comment: I appreciate all of the help, but I am still missing something somewhere.  I'm running the loop, but i'm missing how/where to append appropriately

Comment: @Jason I've updated the question with a function to generate the markup...did it quick so watch for bugs. Though I do not have to big picture on what you are doing, does this serve your needs?

Comment: this almost works - except it is wrapping each store in a ul - so I'm getting 20+ uls.

Comment: see fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/hzZ8j/ - it's wrapping each store in a ul, instead of having 3 uls that store li's are appended to

Comment: @Jason saw that my mistake...I've updated the answer. Let me know how that works for ya.

Comment: Broken - it generates the first ul but does not append any data

Comment: @Jason I've been updating these pretty quick there is likely a bug in it but I think the logic is there...I'll have a look.

Comment: @Jason I updated the answer and fiddle for you, that should do it.

Comment: fantastic - you certainly went out of your way and I appreciate it

Comment: @Jason no problem...it's Friday and I wanted to make 1K rep before the weekend. Have a good one!

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the modulus operator?

```
if(index % 2 == 0) {
    list = $('.storeListLeft');
} else {
    list = $('.storeListRight');
}
```

Even indexes will return 0 and odd indexes will return 1.

Comment: modulus won't work due to the alphabetical order after the initial item